# Should Triage review be available after using all daily votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, triage

I used all my daily votes today, so "First Post" and "Late Answer" were no longer available ... but Triage review queue was.

Is this intentional?

No biggie, just an f.y.i. in case was overlooked.

Comment: the triage queue doesn't let you down/upvote, so why would it block after you spent your votes?

Comment: ahh, had not thought of that... thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting is not required in Triage, so there's no requirement that you be able to vote to review there.

We *do* offer the opportunity to vote *after* reviewing a post in some cases, but that doesn't actually affect the outcome of your review - it's essentially a convenience feature so that you don't need to click through to the full question page, and it respects all of the normal restrictions on voting.